# What can I use to measure some properties in a 3D (x,y,z) ?Regionprops docu says it's only for (N, M) but I found information of a 3D regionprops PR

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, numpy-ndarray, ndimage

Link to regionprops documentation:
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops

PR of Regionprops info:
https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1505

Comment: See also https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the documentation needs updating! You can use `regionprops` directly on 3D images for many properties. Those that are 2D-only (e.g. perimeter) will raise an error if you ask for them on a 3D image. We will try to update the documentation so that all of this is clearly indicated.

Comment: Thanks again Juan.